# Child View Controller too small

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have a button that opens up a folder, which is a separate View Controller, and in that view there are 4 more buttons. When one of these is opened up it is supposed to open a new view as a child view controller on top of the other views. The only problem is that it only opens it in the folder view, making the new window too small. I even tried just having it push to a new view controller but that was not working right either. Here is the code of the problem. If anyone knows a fix I would greatly appreciate it.

```
   -(IBAction)DetailEvent1:(id)sender{

    TableDetailViewController  *objDetail = [[TableDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TableDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self addChildViewController:objDetail];
    objDetail.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 560.0f);
    [self.view addSubview:objDetail.view];
}
```

Comment: Why couldn't you push it? Have you tried to add it to `self.parentViewController`?

Comment: No what would be the full line of code for parentViewController?